# Letsencrypt certificate READY is False and the STATUS is 'Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist'

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I am trying to configure tls for my Kubernetes cluster using cert-manager and lets encrypt but seems to be running into a problem that I cannot seem to resolve.

I have installed cert-manager using the following command

```sh
kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.0.1/cert-manager.yaml
```

And have configured cluster issuer with the yaml file below

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: tardis
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: adamlee@tardistechnology.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

And I have tried issuing a certificate with the yaml file below

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: home.tardis.kr
  namespace: tardis
spec:
  secretName: home.tardis.kr-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: home.tardis.kr
  dnsNames:
  - home.tardis.kr
```

However, when I get the status of the certificate, it seems to be 'False' and the status seems to be 'Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist'
[image]
Some of the solutions that I have found seems to indicate that this is due to the fact that the fact that the domain listed on the ingress is not connected properly, but this does not seem to be the case for me, and the domain seems to be connected fine.

It would be deeply appreciated if anyone could provide any feedback on this matter.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was applying certificate instead of secret. I changed the ingress so that it will apply the secret and the problem was solved

Comment: i am facing the same issue as you, could you please elaborate what you did exactly by referencing to your manifests ?